# Can't execute Remarkable markdown editor

Tags: gnome, software-installation, 15.10

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 gnome. I tried to download and install Remarkable using the .deb from [their website](http://remarkableapp.github.io/linux.html) via software centre. Each time it crashes when I attempt to execute it. This is the result from terminal:

```
$ remarkable
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable/__init__.py:27: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable/RemarkableWindow.py:28: PyGIWarning: WebKit was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit
*Spellchecking not enabled.
*To enable spellchecking install pygtkspellcheck
*https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygtkspellcheck/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/remarkable", line 66, in <module>
    remarkable.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable/__init__.py", line 48, in main
    window = RemarkableWindow.RemarkableWindow()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable_lib/Window.py", line 52, in __new__
    builder = get_builder('RemarkableWindow')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable_lib/helpers.py", line 48, in get_builder
    builder.add_from_file(ui_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable_lib/Builder.py", line 86, in add_from_file
    Gtk.Builder.add_from_file(self, filename)
GLib.Error: gtk-builder-error-quark: /usr/share/remarkable/ui/RemarkableWindow.ui:835:58 Object with ID  not found (13)
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

[sitzmoebelchronograph commented a workaround](https://github.com/remarkableapp/Remarkable-Linux/issues/14#issuecomment-181986442) for the crash in the Remarkable Github project issue #14.

> I can confirm this issue.
>
> On my Debian stretch I sloved this by editing
>   /usr/share/remarkable/ui/RemarkableWindow.ui I disabled all stuff from
>   line 834 to 842 like this:
>
> ```
>            <!--
>                 <child>
>                   <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="mnu_about">
>                     <property name="related_action"/>
>                     <property name="visible">True</property>
>                     <property name="can_focus">False</property>
>                     <property name="label" translatable="yes">About</property>
>                     <property name="use_underline">True</property>
>                   </object>
>                 </child>
>                -->
> ```
>
> This will disable the "About" menu entry in remarkables "Help" menu.
>   This will fix the start issue for me. Hope this will help you guys to
>   fix your issues too

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I remember the Remarkable has lot of problem.

I suggest you to use retext instead. just type `sudo apt install retext`.

Comment: I tried ReText, it looks good, very similar to Remarkable.  Works OK with Github-style Markdown.